# view function isn't returning anything

Tags: python, django

The problem here is that when the form is posted the `create_usecase` function runs and then it redirects to another URL. This URL runs the `quest` function in the view and executes every line in the function but it doesn't make any return at all the `create-usecase` template stays as it is.

So the template is like this:

```
<form>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col m2 s4">
                    <p>Case name</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col m10 s8">
                    <input id="usecase_name" type="text" name="usecase_name" placeholder="Case name">
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6 offset-s3">
            <select id="category-list">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your Category</option>
                <option value="1">University/College</option>
                <option value="2">Hospital</option>
                <option value="3">Business Organizations</option>
            </select>
            <label>Categories</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="subcategory-list" class="row">
        <div class="col s6 offset-s3">
            {% if data %}
            <h6>Sub Category</h6>
            {% for item in data %}
            <div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input" onchange="subCategoryValue('{{ item.username }}')" type="radio" name="sub-category" id="{{ item.username }}" value="{{ item.username }}">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{ item.username }}">
                {{ item.username }}
                </label>
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row center">
        <button type="submit" id="nextBtn" class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange">Next</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var flag = ''
        function subCategoryValue(v) {
            flag = v;
            $('#nextBtn').show();
        }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#nextBtn').hide();
        $('#category-list').change(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if($('#usecase_name').val() !== '') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/create-usecase/',
                    data: {
                        usecase_name: $('#usecase_name').val(),
                        category: $('#category-list').val(),
                        sub_category: '',
                        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
                    },
                    success:function(response) {
                        $('#subcategory-list').replaceWith($("#subcategory-list",response));
                    }
                });
            } else {
                alert('Please fill the usecase field.')
            }
        });

    });
    $('#nextBtn').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/create-usecase/',
            data: {
                usecase_name: $('#usecase_name').val(),
                category: $('#category-list').val(),
                sub_category: flag,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
            success:function() {

            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

And the views:

```
def create_usecase(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('index')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if not request.POST['sub_category'] == '':
                print(request.POST['sub_category'])
                #create a use new use case or project in the database
                request.session['usecase_name'] = request.POST['usecase_name']
                request.session['category'] = request.POST['category']
                request.session['sub_category'] = request.POST['sub_category']
                return redirect('quest')
            else:
                users = User.objects.all()
                return render(request, 'usecases/create-usecase.html', {'data': users})
        else:
            return render(request, 'usecases/create-usecase.html')

def quest(request):
    print('questions!')
    print('{} {} {} '.format(request.session['usecase_name'], request.session['category'], request.session['sub_category']))
    return HttpResponse('test')
```

And the urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create-usecase/quest/', views.quest, name='quest'),
    path('create-usecase/', views.create_usecase, name='create_usecase'),
]
```

The console:

```
[17/May/2018 13:57:14] "GET /create-usecase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4376
[17/May/2018 13:57:19] "POST /create-usecase/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5514
test1
[17/May/2018 13:57:23] "POST /create-usecase/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
questions!
test 1 test1
[17/May/2018 13:57:23] "GET /create-usecase/quest/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
```

Comment: You are using Ajax. Your Ajax code literally says "do nothing on successful post". So you should not be surprised that that is what happens.

Comment: so how to make it return render to a template?

Comment: The level of passive aggressiveness gets worse on this site every day...

Comment: well thats because of missing the deadlines my dear

Comment: just put target redirect url in ajax success like  window.location = "/someplace/";

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked